# gatsby config file load scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, gatsby, cache-control

I'm trying to load a few scripts from `gatsby-config.js`
using `gatsby-plugin-load-script` package.
Basically all scripts depend on `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js` script.

So when I run `gatsby develop` all the scripts are loaded and run it nicely, I go to my local host and everything looks nice.
After that I refresh the page, scripts run, but since `three.min.js` it's bigger than the rest (therefore takes longer to be executed) the other scripts failed on run . Also the scripts got cached.

I would like to know if there is a way to sequencially execute the scripts, or a way to not cache the scripts everytime they run.

I looked for some info here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-load-script/ but it's not so well documented.

Any ideas??

Initial Result:

[image]

Result after the page is refreshed:

[image]

*gatsby-config.js*

```
module.exports = {
      siteMetadata: {
        title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
        author: `@gatsbyjs`,
      },
      plugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
          options: {
            name: `images`,
            path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
          },
        },
        {   
          resolve: "gatsby-plugin-load-script", 
          options: {    
            src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js",    
    
          },    
        },  
    
        {   
          resolve: "gatsby-plugin-load-script", 
          options: {    
            src: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-18/CopyShader.js", 
          },    
        },  
    
        {   
          resolve: "gatsby-plugin-load-script", 
          options: {    
            src: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/141552/03_glitch.js",    
    
          },    
        },  
        {   
          resolve: "gatsby-plugin-load-script", 
          options: {    
            src: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-18/EffectComposer.js", 
    
          },    
        },  
        ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result without adding extra plugins, by adding all your scripts in a `<Helmet>` tag. Gatsby's  extends from [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) so you can use in your site to add external scripts in any component by adding the following snippet:

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const AnyPage = () => (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="AnyPage" />
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"/>
      ... and so on
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
)

export default AnyPage
```

`<Helmet>` tag, from their documentation:

> This reusable React component will manage all of your changes to the
>   document head.
>
> Helmet takes plain HTML tags and outputs plain HTML tags. It's dead
>   simple, and React beginner friendly.

Comment: I followed this approach in first instance, but the problem is the following:
`Three.js` gets cached, so when I try to load the page for the second time, the browser takes the `Three js` code from the cache memory (same for the rest of the scripts) and since is the biggest one, is the last to be loaded, so everything breaks because the other scripts depends on `Three.js` script

I posted some screenshots above :)

So what I was also thinking is to pause the loading of the rest of scripts untill `Three.js` is loaded...